# Elementos inseridos via .html() e ação das teclas com jQuery

Tags: jquery

A idéia do código é a de pesquisar produtos e inserir o link do produto quando o usuário selecionar o link do registro como um produto vinculado. Ao clicar no `input[type='radio']`, um novo campo é inserido abaixo do campo da URL através do .html() do jQuery.

Inseri um retorno de log no console para saber se o código estava reconhecendo o evento .keyup() do campo, mas não há respostas.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("input.tipoURL").on('click',function() {
  
    var value = $(this).val();
    
    if(value=='prod') {
    
      $('#prURL').val('');
      $('#return').html("<input type='text' name='listaProd' id='listaProd' placeholder='Pesquise pelo produto'/><div id='returnProd'></div>");
      
    } else if(value='link') {
    
      $("#prURL").val('');
      $("#return").html('');
      
    }
    
  });
  
  $('#listaProd').keyup(function(e){
  
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).val();
    var contaChar = value.length;
    
    window.alert('Acessou');
    
    if(contaChar<=3) {
      $('#returnProd').html('');
    }
    
    if(contaChar>3) {
      $("#returnProd").load("lista.php?prod=" + value,function(data){
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
    
  });
  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' name='prURL' id='prURL'/>

<label for='tipoURLlink'><input id='tipoURLlink' type='radio' name='tipoURL' value='link' id='tipoURL' class='tipoURL' checked/> Link</label>

<label for='tipoURLprod'><input id='tipoURLprod' type='radio' name='tipoURL' value='prod' class="tipoURL"/> Produto</label>

<div id='return'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está inserindo um elemento no DOM de forma dinâmica, e a associação do evento `keyup` foi feita antes do elemento existir, o mesmo não é executado.

Altere a linha:

```
$('#listaProd').keyup(function(e){
```

Por:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#listaProd', function(e){
```

Desta forma, você passa a interceptar qualquer evento `keyup` dentro do documento que contenha o id `#listaProd`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("input.tipoURL").on('click',function() {
  
    var value = $(this).val();
    
    if(value=='prod') {
    
      $('#prURL').val('');
      $('#return').html("<input type='text' name='listaProd' id='listaProd' placeholder='Pesquise pelo produto'/><div id='returnProd'></div>");
      
    } else if(value='link') {
    
      $("#prURL").val('');
      $("#return").html('');
      
    }
    
  });
  
  $(document).on('keyup', '#listaProd', function(e){
  
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).val();
    var contaChar = value.length;
    
    window.alert('Acessou');
    
    if(contaChar<=3) {
      $('#returnProd').html('');
    }
    
    if(contaChar>3) {
      $("#returnProd").load("lista.php?prod=" + value,function(data){
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
    
  });
  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' name='prURL' id='prURL'/>

<label for='tipoURLlink'><input id='tipoURLlink' type='radio' name='tipoURL' value='link' id='tipoURL' class='tipoURL' checked/> Link</label>

<label for='tipoURLprod'><input id='tipoURLprod' type='radio' name='tipoURL' value='prod' class="tipoURL"/> Produto</label>

<div id='return'></div>
```

Comment: é uma boa prática generalizar o uso de $(document).on('keyup'),...... ou somente para casos específicos de manipulação de conteúdo gerado via DOM ? Grato.